# Shipping by continent

Tags: expresso-store, shipping

We're using expresso store on a new site. Our client will ship his product based on three flat rates: UK, Europe and Rest of the world.

Quite frankly we can't figure out how to set something like this on Expresso. We used Cartthrob in the past and we remember they have a "GLOBAL" shipping destination variable but can't seem to find the same thing on Expresso. We tried creating one shipping option per region and leaving the match to "any country, any city" but it doesn't seem to be updating any charges. I'm sure this is a fairly common scenario.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

S-

Comment: I'm in the same boat, would love to hear a solution for this. In my case I simply want to select multiple countries for a single shipping rule, since that's how the shipping costs will vary (Royal Mail split international shipping costs into 3 basic "zones" that include many countries each). Otherwise I would have to create around 50 shipping rules that are identical in every way except for the single country varying in each, which would be ridiculously labour intensive for a simple task

Comment: From researching this further, I am hoping it is possible to make a shipping plugin to add new entries to the countries list, acting as arrays of countries that can be selected from any shipping rule. I can't find documentation for how to develop shipping plugins, however. I'd love to hear from the Expresso Store developers on whether this is possible or not.

Comment: Could you please make comments in the comment field? This isn't an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I did go to change that after posting but I apparently need more reputation points to comment. It seemed more helpful to leave the above comment than to delete it altogether.

Comment: Also to update, after further research I can see that Shipping Zones is one of the highest voted feature requests on the Expresso Store site (https://www.exp-resso.com/support/feature-requests). I would assume from that there will not be an easy solution by creating a shipping solution, but would love to hear from the developers whether there is any kind of stop-gap solution available through creating a shipping plugin.